# Command Object forgets to validate from time to time?

Tags: grails, command-objects

I am using Grails 1.3.7 and I have similar code in multiple controllers:

```
def myAction = { MyCommand cmd ->
    if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
        // return bad request
    } else {
        someService.callSomeMethod(cmd.someId)
        ...
    }
}

class MyCommand {
    Long someId

    static constraints = {
        someId nullable: false
    }
}
```

It works just fine 99.99% of the time. However, there are several cases where application logs indicate that the service was called with a null (i.e. cmd.someId returned null). However, that just does not make sense since the constraint is set to `nullable: false`. It feels like that in those very rare cases grails forgot to call `validate()` on the command object or the constraint was ignored.

Any hints for the cause of such problem would be appreciated.